# ¿Cómo se deben asignar los valores a un arreglo de punteros?

Tags: c++, array, poo, punteros

En una tarea me exigen que implemente una función de la forma `B** f(string, int&);` (prototipo inmodificable) en donde el valor de retorno (según entiendo) es un *puntero a un arreglo de punteros* de tipo `B`.

El caso es que quiero generar, a partir de un arreglo estático de elementos de un tipo `A`, un arreglo estático de elementos de un tipo `B**`, el cual voy a retornar al final de la función para luego (desde otra función) recorrerlo y mostrar sus elementos.

No tengo problema en obtener los elementos del tipo `A`, pero desconozco como generar el arreglo de tipo `B**` con dicha información.

### Abajo detallo lo que quiero hacer (compila pero se rompe):

#### A.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

class A {
public:
    char get();
    void set(char);
private:
    char a;
};

#endif
```

#### B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

class B {
public:
    char get();
    void set(char);
private:
    char b;
};

#endif
```

#### X.hpp

```
#ifndef X_HPP
#define X_HPP
#define M 2
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    A arA[M];
    B *arB[M];
    B **f(string s, int &n);
};

#endif
```

#### A.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

char A::get() {
    return a;
}

void A::set(char c) {
    this->a=c;
}
```

#### B.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"

char B::get() {
    return b;
}

void B::set(char c) {
    this->b=c;
}
```

#### X.cpp

```
#include "X.hpp"

B ** X::f(string s, int &n) {
    int i;
    char a=arA[i].get();
    arB[i]->set(a);
    return arB;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "X.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A a;
    X x;
    B**b;
    string s="";
    int n=1;
    a.set('A');
    b=x.f(s,n);
    cout<<b[0]->get()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No queda claro cuál es el objetivo de la función `B** f(string, int&);`. ¿Qué se supone que debe hacer? ¿puedes ampliar los datos de la pregunta?

Comment: En esta función: Cada elemento de un arreglo de tipo A, debe ser copiado a un arreglo de tipo B**, y al final retornar la primera posición de dicho arreglo. Posteriormente: Otra función debe ser capaz de recorrer el arreglo retornado por la primera función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en las respuestas de ustedes y junto a mi compañero de equipo, llegamos a la siguiente solución:

**A.hpp**

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

class A {
public:
    A() {a=0;}
    int get() {return a;}
    void set(int m) {a=m;}
private:
    int a;
};

#endif
```

**B.hpp**

```
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

class B {
public:
    B() {b=0;}
    int get() {return b;}
    void set(int n) {b=n;}
private:
    int b;
};

#endif
```

**X.hpp**

```
#ifndef X_HPP
#define X_HPP
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#define M 3
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    X();
    A arA[M];
    B *arB[M];
    B **f();
};

#endif
```

**X.cpp**

```
#include "X.hpp"

X::X() {
    for (int i=0; i<M; ++i) arA[i] = A();
    for (int i=0; i<M; ++i) arB[i] = new B;
}

B ** X::f() {
    for (int i=0; i<M; ++i) arB[i]->set(arA[i].get());
    return &arB[0];
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "X.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {   
    X x;
    B** b;
    for (int i=0; i<M; ++i) x.arA[i].set(1);
    b=x.f();
    for (int i=0; i<M; ++i) cout<<b[i]->get();
    return 0;
}
```

Aplicamos los mismos principios al proyecto principal y funciono perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

```
class X {
public:
    A arA[M];
    B *arB[M];
    B **f(string s, int &n);
};

B ** X::f(string s, int &n) {
    int i;
    char a=arA[i].get();
    arB[i]->set(a);
    return arB;
}
```

No se si te has fijado pero `arB` no está inicializada en ningún sitio, luego al ejecutar la instrucción `arB[i]->set(a)`, `arB[i]` no apunta a una posición de memoria válida y el resultado suele ser desastroso.

En tu caso una solución sencilla podría ser eliminar el doble puntero en `X` y devolver una referencia de dicho objeto (lo que implica un doble puntero):

```
class X {
public:
    A arA[M];
    B arB[M];
    B **f(string s, int &n);
};

B ** X::f(string s, int &n) {
    int i;
    char a=arA[i].get();
    arB[i].set(a);
    return &arB;
}
```

EDITO: Esto no soluciona otros muchos problemas de tu código. Te enumero algunos de `X::f()` pero el resto del programa está sembrado:

- `i` no está inicializada.
- `n` y `s` no se usa absolutamente para nada. ¿Para qué tiene entonces parámetros la función?
- Seguro que la función ha de hacer una copia de `arA` a `arB`??
- `arA` no está incializado. ¿Que valor hay almacenado en `arA[0]` o en `arA[1]`? Lo mismo es aplicable a `arB`.
- Sería de agradecer que `A` tuviese implementado el constructor por defecto para inicializar los miembros de la clase. Vale que `A` no pertenece a `X::f()`, pero se usa en `arA`. Lo mismo aplicable para `B`.

Un saludo.

Comment: Tampoco está inicializada la `i` de la función `X::f`, con lo que cualquier llamada que indexe un arreglo a través de `i` causa también comportamiento no definido.

Comment: Cierto. Y si te fijas verás que `n` no se usa para nada... quizás la idea es que `n` sustituyese a `i`, en cuyo caso también habría que comprobar si `n` está en el rango válido [0,1], dado que `arB` únicamente tiene dos elementos... pero ya era mucho presuponer.

Comment: es que ya no he entrado a valorar nada más... sin saber exáctamente qué se espera de `X::f` no hay nada que podamos hacer por responder a la pregunta y analizar el código es tan sólo una pérdida de tiempo; con un sólo vistazo he encontrado muchos fallos que no añadiré en una respuesta por lo ya mencionado.

Comment: Te entiendo perfectamente. Yo me he centrado en intentar responder a la pregunta y he obviado todo lo demás porque si no la respuesta iba a ser demasiado extensa

Comment: El objetivo de X::f es copiar cada elemento de un arreglo tipo A a un arreglo tipo B**, string s es la clave con la cual obtengo los valores de A, int &n es la cantidad de elementos del arreglo tipo A. Pero por el momento lo único que me causa problemas es retornar el arreglo tipo B** para su posterior recorrido. Escribí este código para limitar la función a realizar solo esa tarea y así poder aislar el problema.

Answer (score -1):

Sigue sin quedar claro el objetivo que persigues, la utilidad y expectativas de la función `X::f` ni la estructura del código en general; voy a intentar dar respuesta a algunas cosas a ver si conseguimos aclarar los puntos oscuros.

> El objetivo de X::f es copiar cada elemento de un arreglo tipo A a un arreglo tipo B**

Esto carece totalmente de sentido. El tipo `A` y el tipo `B**` (puntero a puntero a `B`) son completamente incompatibles, no sólo por ser diferentes tipos (`A` y `B`) si no porque punteros e instancias no son lo mismo. Creo que te estás haciendo un lío o yo te estoy entendiendo mal.

Un arreglo de tipo `A` es una secuencia de **instancias** de `A` contiguas en memoria, un arreglo de tipo `B**` es una secuencia de **punteros a punteros a instancias** de `B`, todos esos punteros también contiguos en memoria.

> string s es la clave con la cual obtengo los valores de A

Si estás indexando elementos mediante una clave, no estamos hablando de un arreglo si no de un contenedor asociativo, podría ser (por ejemplo) un [mapa](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map); pese a tu comentario no me es posible localizar en ninguna parte del código que has compartido ninguna indexación de ningún dato mediante `string`.

> int &n es la cantidad de elementos del arreglo tipo A

Es posible que así sea, pero al ser un parámetro de tipo referencia, me da por pensar en la posibilidad de que se espere que sea un parámetro de lectura y escritura, así pues puede ser que se facilite `n` para leer la cantidad de elementos del arreglo de `A`s no para asignarlos... claro que es sólo una conjetura, no hay nada en tu código que ayude a esclarecer nada.

> Pero por el momento lo único que me causa problemas es retornar el arreglo tipo B** para su posterior recorrido.

Para empezar, no indicas que problemas te causa tu solución... pero en realidad, seas cuales sean son el menor de tus problemas, a parte de los problemas ya mencionados por [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6919/2742), el tipo `B**` que devuelves en `X::f` es en realidad un dato interno de la clase `X`, en concreto el miembro `X::arB` cuyo tipo es `B*[M]` (arreglo de M elementos de punteros a `B`) en el momento en que lo devuelves en `X::f` decae a `B**` perdiendo la información de tamaño y violando el principio de [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)), aunque dicho encapsulamiento ya lo estabas ignorando al hacer los miembros públicos.

En general los arreglos de punteros como `B**` se suelen usar para arreglos de dos dimensiones o arreglos “*diente de sierra*” (arreglos de dos dimensiones con cantidad irregular de elementos en cada índice. Deduzco que la función `X::f` pretende transformar algo en un arreglo de dos dimensiones de tipos `B`, pero sigue siendo tan sólo una conjetura.

Para recorrer el arreglo de `B**` (o cualquier otro arreglo de dos dimensiones) debes hacer un doble bucle:

```
for (int x = 0; x < limite_x; ++x)
    for (int y = 0; y < limite_y; ++y)
        std::cout << b[x][y] << ‘\n’;
```

Pero no puedo estar seguro de que esto sea lo que buscas pues no queda claro tu objetivo.

Comment: El prototipo de X::f lo puse tal cual me lo pedían en la tarea. Ignoren los parámetros (estuve mal en escribirlos si no los iba a usar para la pregunta). Aquí mi principal problema es que no tenia ni idea de que es lo que era B** (puntero a puntero es lo único que entendía). Ahora entiendo que lo que necesito es generar un nuevo B** a partir de un A. Los arreglos los necesito públicos ya que los prototipos del resto de las funciones que me piden no tienen en sus parámetros el arreglo a modificar. Necesito hacer ejecucion.modificarAlgo(); cada vez que quiero ingresar | borrar alguna cosa.

Comment: ¿Y cómo se realiza la conversión de `A` a `B`? ¿Y cómo se realiza la conversión de un arreglo de `A` a arreglo de punteros a punteros a `B`?

Comment: B es capaz de almacenar la misma información que A, por lo tanto se puede copiar. Las conversiones no son necesarias.